# Dynamics AX RGB Color Problems

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Dynamics AX 2012 R2

I am using Image:rgb(r, g, b); to convert from RGB to integer colors.

When the colors display, they are all shifted--the red and blue values appear to be swapped, but I think it is actually more complicated than that.

255,0,0 displays as blue (should be red)
0,0,255 displays as red (should be blue)
Any colors in-between all come in mixed up as well.  I can trade the r & b values, but that doesn't seem like the right answer, considering I'm using a stock AX method for the 
conversion that is documented as r, g, b not b, g, r.

It is possible the problem may not be with the Image::rgb method at all.  If I manually convert the rgb value and just pass an integer to it, the colors are still reversed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WinAPI::RGB2int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/winapi.rgb2int.aspx) method to convert from RGB to its internal representation.